After being dismissed for a safeguarding issue from a childcare work place is this something that would appear on an enhanced DBS check?
I have previously worked with children in a preschool, I recently been dismissed due to a safeguarding allegation my past manager referred this is this likely to appear on a new enhanced DBS check?
